How do I set the ACLs/Folder permissions on a zfs dataset to allow SMB share with Samba?
Background info:

Linux Mint 22
Installed zfs tools
Installed Samba to enable smb sharing
I am new to Linux and I'm sure there is just a missing piece somewhere.

What I have Done So Far:
I created a zfs dataset and changed the following properties:
sudo zfs set nbmans=on sharesmb=on NASMainPool/WNAS 

I made my account as the owner of the file with:
sudo chmod 1000 /NASMainPool/WNAS

Then going through the Nemo GUI I went to:
NASMainPool/WNAS -> Properties -> "share".
Tried to enable share and allow for guest access -> got prompted to add additional permissions -> Clicked Add -> got this error:
"Could not changer permissions of folder "WNAS".
What ACL/Permissions setting am I missing?


